# Yiistrap: how can I get value of TbHtml::navbarSearchForm

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I need get value of texfield of TbHtml::navbarSearchForm

```
TbHtml::navbarSearchForm("/$valueSearch"),'post',array('inputOptions' =>array ('name' =>'text[field]','class'=>'search-query','placeholder'=>  Yii::t('app', 'search a value?!!!!'))),
```

How can I get value such as this:

```
$valueSearch='value';
```

Comment: Why you want "get" a value by rendering an UI-Element? Cant follow you.

Comment: I'd get the value that the user entered in search field

Comment: Ehhhh, right after sending your Form try get -> $_POST['text']['field'] ?